# Rails: Todo is created and rendered as "/todos" on the HTML page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I haven't used Ruby/Rails in years. I am trying to get up and running with just a basic functioning Todo CRUD app.

**App/models/todo.rb**

```
class Todo < ApplicationRecord
end
```

**db/schema**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2019_06_25_070433) do

  create_table "todos", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.string "body"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

end
```

The problem is when I submit a todo it renders as "/todos".

http://localhost:3000/todos

The page renders as:

[image]

Here are the (incomplete) controller actions.

```
class TodosController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @todos = Todo.all
  end

  def show
    @todo = Todo.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
  end

  def new
    @todo = Todo.new
  end

  def create
    @todo = Todo.new(params[:title])    # I am not sure about the correct syntax for params. I want the title AND body
    @todo.save
    redirect_to @todo

  end

  def edit
  end

  def destroy
  end
end
```

**new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_with model: @todo do |form| %>
  <%= form.text_field :title %>
  <%= form.label :body%>
  <%= form.text_field :body %>
  <%= form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

When I submit a "todo" the page redirect to the show route and when the HTML page renders it does not display the "todo".

**show.html.erb**

```
<ul>
  <%= @todo.title %>
</ul>
```

The rails terminal shows the following:

```
Started POST "/todos" for ::1 at 2019-06-25 09:41:45 -0700
Processing by TodosController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"x29t72XmHgzZ49Lg3fu/11z2U0p5bSE1RpZhRyxzIqzvtCUuCnMhfbYF6ndYq7OU58aBtNggdYzSEsmQlGKwHQ==", "todo"=>{"title"=>"Hello ", "body"=>"World"}, "commit"=>"Create Todo"}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/todos_controller.rb:19
  Todo Create (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "todos" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)  [["created_at", "2019-06-25 16:41:45.054400"], ["updated_at", "2019-06-25 16:41:45.054400"]]
  ↳ app/controllers/todos_controller.rb:19
   (4.4ms)  commit transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/todos_controller.rb:19
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/todos/32
Completed 200 OK in 8ms (ActiveRecord: 4.9ms)


Started GET "/todos/32" for ::1 at 2019-06-25 09:41:45 -0700
Processing by TodosController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"32"}
  Todo Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "todos".* FROM "todos" WHERE "todos"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 32], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/todos_controller.rb:7
  Rendering todos/show.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered todos/show.html.erb within layouts/application (0.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 13ms (Views: 11.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)
```

When I run the seed command to populate the app with dummy data it renders fine.

**seeds.rb**

```
Todo.create(title: 'AAA', body: 'aaa')
Todo.create(title: 'BBB', body: 'bbb')
Todo.create(title: 'CCC', body: 'ccc')
Todo.create(title: 'DDD', body: 'ddd')
```

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Can you show your Todo model? My guess is that you have a validation checking that the body must be present, and since you are only passing in title in the created action, the `@todo.save` line fails. Since the Todo wasn't saved, it can't redirect you to it at the end of the create method and redirects to index instead. Redirecting to an unsaved record redirects to that record's index page instead.

Btw you can use `params.permit(:title, :body)` to pass in those attrs to Todo.new. If I'm right about the validation, changing that line would fix it. Or add a `valid?` check in the controller.

Comment: I added it to the question above.

Comment: `title` and `body` are inside the `todo` key in your `params`. You'd need `params.require(:todo).permit(:title, :body)`

Comment: @fanta is correct. So you don't seem to have any validations in the model, but are you sure the Todo is correctly saving? I'm still a bit suspicious of `@todo.save`. Do you see new entries in the todos table after hitting create?

Comment: If you see that it's usually that you have no link text specified, as in `@link.title` is blank. If not then it's a case of supplying the arguments to `link_to` in the wrong order.